# How to bind multiple collections to a single ul using Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a view model with two observable arrays:

- `assignedItems`
- `requiredDropPoints`

In the view I want do something like this

```html
<ul>

    <!-- ko foreach: assignedItems -->
    <li>
       <!-- display item-->
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko foreach: requiredDropPoints-->
    <li>
       <!-- display different item-->
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->

</ul>
```

I can do `ko if: expression` after the first `foreach` and it works fine, but the 2nd `foreach` won't work. Is there a way to get what I need?

Comment: Might need to see more of your code. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/nigelw/f2jzqx6g

Comment: Interesting. I the only thing different is that my ul is nested 3 levels deep inside two other ul-foreach.

Comment: I mocked it up in jsfiddle, and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/jpetrak/6ahzjamL/4/

Comment: so I created another using my json model and template but stripped out css classes, event and custom bindings. Rendered fine. It's probably a binding error that doesn't hinder an Ko if but does a for each. I have enough to narrow it down now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your collections with ko.computed and bind list items to resulting computed:

```
composite = ko.computed(function() {
  var result = [];
  result.push.apply(result, assignedItems());
  result.push.apply(result, requiredDropPoints());
  return result;
});

<ul>
    <!-- ko foreach: composite -->
    <li>
       <!-- display item-->
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

In this composite you can also filter items, map them or do some additional processing.